# How to declare cursor as global variable

Tags: android, variables, cursor

i have two classes,MainActivity.java and ImageAdapter.java i have declared cursor in main activity like this

```
public  Cursor cursor;
```

now i want to access that variable 'cursor' in my second class named imageAdapter.java.How it will be possible in good way guys?

Comment: `make public static Cursor cursor;` Now it's complete.

Comment: sorry its not workng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `ImageAdapter` extends `CursorAdapter` then use in `MainActivity`

```
adapter.swapCursor(yourCursor);
```

and in `ImageAdapter` then call `getCursor()`

If `ImageAdapter` is not extended from `CursorAdapter`, then you can implement set methods in it.

```
private Cursor cursor;

public void setCursor(Cursor cursor){
    this.cursor = cursor;
}
```

And set it in `MainActivity` like `imageAdapter.setCursor(yourCursor)`;

This is usually better from OOP perspective than declaring cursor in `MainActivity` as static or creating your `ImageAdapter` dependant from `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the cursor to adapter like this

```
imageAdapter adapter = new imageAdapter(MainActivity.this, cursor);
```

You can assess this cursor from your adapter class.

```
Cursor cursor;
public imageAdapter(Activity activity, Cursor cursor) {
    this.cursor = cursor;
}
```

Now you can access the data of cursor in the `getView(...)` method.

Answer (score -1):

did you try creating getter and setter for the variable???or you can just make it static by

```
public static  Cursor cursor;
```

and access it like:

```
MainActivity.cursor;
```

or if you make getter and setter you can acess it like:

```
MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
m.getCursor();
m.setCursor(new Cursor);
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: `new` with an activity is always plain wrong, and static variable members are a bad idea.